# How to convince NSTextView that text starts at the bottom?

Tags: macos, nstextview

I will append some strings to `NSTextView`, but I want them to start at the bottom. New appended string should go underneath the last appended string.

In Java or C#, one can set `VerticalAligment = bottom`, but I can't find any appropriate way to achieve this in Cocoa... Any thoughts?

**EDIT:**
I guess I didn't specify precisely enough what I want, so I'll append two pictures. First is what it looks now, second one is what I want. Basically, the newest string is always at the bottom and the older ones gets pushed up. Makes sense now?

[image] [image]

Comment: Do you mean underneath visually?  If you precede your freshly appended string with a newline character like `\n`, it should be directly below whatever was there already.

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't answer how to start at the bottom of nstextview... Or am I missing something?

Comment: Either method: `func stringByAppendingString(_ aString: String) -> String` (Swift) or `- (NSString *)stringByAppendingString:(NSString *)aString` (ObjC) appends to right of the receiver, so by preceding the new string with ` \n`, it will appear on the very next line below what is already there.

Comment: I don't think we undersrand each other. I'm aware of \n thing, but my problem lies somewhere else...  How can I force NSTextview to draw first string at the bottom. Next one will still be at the bottom and previous one will go abowe new one. An so on... Is it clear now?

Comment: Wait, you mean that you want a long empty space ABOVE the very first string?  And this empty space would diminish as you append more strings?

Comment: Added pictures to clarify my question.

Comment: I see.  Looks cool.  I have no idea off the top of my head.  I am sure the answer lies in NSTextContainer class somewhere.  I will look around the docs a little when I get some time.

Comment: Please do, if you'll have some time to spare. For now, I'll use `[self scrollToEndOfDocument:nil];` Not exactly what I want... But when life gives you lemons... :)